# How can I get Enzyme to recognise the react-html-attrs plugin?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using Jest to test my React components. I have the react-html-attrs plugin enabled allowing me to use `class` instead of `className`. This is configured through Webpack's module loaders property with:

```js
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modeules|bower_components/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  query: {
    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
    plugins: [
      'react-html-attrs',
      'transform-decorators-legacy',
      'transform-class-properties',
      'babel-polyfill'
    ],
  }
}
```

I'm wanting to use Enzyme to test the rendered outcome of my components in order to assert whether these `class` attributes are correctly provided, but I'm getting the following error:

> console.error node_modules\fbjs\lib\warning.js:36
>        **Warning: Unknown DOM property class.
>
>         Did you mean className?**
>          in h1
>          in Heading

This is my test script:

```js
it('loads the correct icon', () => {
  const render = shallow(
    <Heading icon="fa-question" text="This is a test" />
  );

  const el = render.find('i');

  expect(el.hasClass('fa-question')).toBe(true);
});
```

The Heading component itself is this:

```js
return (
  <h1 class="heading">
    {icon ? <i class={"fa " + icon}></i> : ""} {text}
  </h1>
)
```

...and the output (seen through a react-test-renderer Snapshot) is:

```
<h1
  class="heading">
  <i
    class="fa fa-question" />

  This is a test
</h1>
```

How can I get Enzyme to recognise that `class` is valid with react-html-attrs enabled?

---

#### Update

When logging `render`[`.html()`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/html.html) I can see that Enzyme has ignored the `class` attributes completely:

> console.info src\js\components__tests__\Heading.js:40
>    `<h1><i></i> This is a test</h1>`

#### Update 2

Here is my Jest config within package.json:

```css
"jest": {
  "modulePaths": [
    "./src/js"
  ],
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js"
  ],
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "shared"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
  },
  "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
    "node_modules/react/",
    "node_modules/enzyme/"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using webpack with the same configuration before running the tests?

Comment: @DavinTryon I'm not really sure what you mean by that. I've added my Jest config to the question.

Comment: I guess I'm asking how the tests know about your webpack config :)  I don't use Jest, but the config could be useful for someone who does.

Comment: Do you have a .babelrc file as well?  you might need to add the plugin there if the tests are not using the webpack config.

Comment: @DavinTryon yes, that's set up with `"presets": ["es2015", "react"]`. I get what you're saying, but unfortunately this is my first time using Jest so I've no idea how to get it to be aware of Webpack. Their documentation is a little confusing - perhaps I just need to do a little more reading first.

Comment: cool, so in the .babelrc, you can also have a `"plugins"` array.  I'd try and add the same list of plugins that you have in your webpack config to the .babelrc and see if Jest will pick them up.  Should work.  Maybe try adding just the `react-html-attrs` first.

Comment: BTW, the webpack `babel-loader` will pick up from the .babelrc if no config is given in the webpack.config.js.  So, you only need the config once.

Comment: @DavinTryon hey, what do you know, it works! I'd never thought to do anything with the .babelrc file. Thank you very much! Feel free to add that as an answer and I'll gladly accept.

Comment: Cool, well done. I guess Jest must hide all the babel wiring. Glad you got it sorted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Jest doesn't use the webpack config, you need to add your babel configuration to a source that it will read.  The .babelrc file is a good place for this because webpack will also look there for configuration of the `babel-loader`.

So, adding this to your .bablerc should help:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "react",
        "stage-0"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "react-html-attrs",
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "transform-class-properties",
        "babel-polyfill"
    ]
}
```

Then, you can clean up your webpack config as well:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modeules|bower_components/,
  loader: 'babel'
}
```